# Help with layouting game scores in android

Tags: android

I am still trying to understand now android layouts work. I am developing an application for displaying soccers results for a brazilian championship. I will have a list view for displaying the last game scores, like the image in the url below (extracted from an iphone aplication).

http://grem.io/images/score.jpg

I cant see how i can do this. I also need to say that i am a trully beginner on this.

Thanks
T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accomplish the screenshot's layout using [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html). The left and right images can have `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` respectively on their declarations. As for the center content you could declare `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` to get it anchored to the top and `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` to get it centered correctly. You can then assign an id to that top TextView (or whatever you make it), and then align the other two TextViews below it.

You'll have to mess around with margins to get the Views looking nice space-wise, but the above layout parameters will get you started with organizing the Views.

Comment: All right, i will give a try on your suggestion and will post the layout code here once I am done. Thanks McStretch

Comment: it seems i cant post the xml in the comment box, but it is perfect the solution you gave me. Thanks again